# Pandas, group by with max return AssertionError:

Tags: python, pandas

There's something wrong with pandas, and I would like your opinion,

I've this Dataframe where I need to get the max values, code is just below,

```
df_stack=pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98101.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.6122, -122.33799, 1927.0, 57.85220900338872,
        59.91269863912585],
       [1.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98101.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.61317, -122.33393, 1996.0, 55.82342114189166,
        56.86951201265458],
       [3.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98101.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.61393, -122.3381, 1969.0, 76.68191235628086,
        77.37931271575705],
       [5.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98101.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.61412, -122.33664, 1926.0, 68.53505428597694,
        71.00764283155655],
       [8.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98121.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.61375, -122.34047, 1980.0, 67.01346098859122,
        68.34485815906346]], columns=['OSEBuildingID', 'DataYear', 'BuildingType', 'PrimaryPropertyType', 
 'ZipCode', 'Neighborhood', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'YearBuilt', 
 'SourceEUI(KWm2)', 'SourceEUIWN(KWm2)' ])
```

When I run the code below :

```
df_stack[['OSEBuildingID', 
          'DataYear', 
          'BuildingType', 
          'PrimaryPropertyType', 
          'ZipCode', 'Neighborhood', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 
          'YearBuilt', 'SourceEUI(KWm2)', 'SourceEUIWN(KWm2)']].groupby('OSEBuildingID').max()
```

I get an error, "AssertionError: " the same you'll probably get if you try this.
But, when I comment this two columns and I run the code again

```
df_stack[['OSEBuildingID', 
          'DataYear', 
          #'BuildingType', 
          #'PrimaryPropertyType', 
          'ZipCode', 'Neighborhood', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 
          'YearBuilt', 'SourceEUI(KWm2)', 'SourceEUIWN(KWm2)']].groupby('OSEBuildingID').max()
```

I get the results

```
     DataYear  ZipCode Neighborhood  Latitude  Longitude  YearBuilt  SourceEUI(KWm2)  SourceEUIWN(KWm2)
OSEBuildingID                                                                                                    
1.0              2016.0  98101.0     DOWNTOWN  47.61317 -122.33393     1996.0        57.852209          59.912699
3.0              2016.0  98101.0     DOWNTOWN  47.61393 -122.33810     1969.0        76.681912          77.379313
5.0              2016.0  98101.0     DOWNTOWN  47.61412 -122.33664     1926.0        68.535054          71.007643
8.0              2016.0  98121.0     DOWNTOWN  47.61375 -122.34047     1980.0        67.013461          68.344858
```

If I replace max() by mean() I can uncomment those 2 lines and runc the code with no problem.
This behaviour it only happens with max() and min(), well I just test max, mean and min, 
But I need to get the max.

Thank you if can help.

Comment: What is your `pd.__version__`

Comment: What does the error message say? What result do you get when you run mean()?

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [regression in `1.0.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.1/whatsnew/v1.0.1.html#fixed-regressions) that was fixed with `'1.0.1'`, so I suggest you upgrade your version.

> Fixed regression in .groupby().agg() raising an AssertionError for some **reductions like min on object-dtype columns** (GH31522)

Comment: I want to leave a comment here for those like myself- I have version 1.0.1 installed, and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Carlos Carvalho , when I run this code, I don't get any errors. Can you confirm you still get the error if you copy and paste this into your terminal? As implied in a comment above, it might have to do with your version. Also, **BuildingType** and **PrimaryPropertyTypes** are objects and not floats, but it should still work:

```
df_stack=pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98101.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.6122, -122.33799, 1927.0, 57.85220900338872,
        59.91269863912585],
       [1.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98101.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.61317, -122.33393, 1996.0, 55.82342114189166,
        56.86951201265458],
       [3.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98101.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.61393, -122.3381, 1969.0, 76.68191235628086,
        77.37931271575705],
       [5.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98101.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.61412, -122.33664, 1926.0, 68.53505428597694,
        71.00764283155655],
       [8.0, 2016.0, 'NonResidential', 'Hotel', 98121.0, 'DOWNTOWN',
        47.61375, -122.34047, 1980.0, 67.01346098859122,
        68.34485815906346]], columns=['OSEBuildingID', 'DataYear', 'BuildingType', 
                                      'PrimaryPropertyType', 
 'ZipCode', 'Neighborhood', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'YearBuilt', 
 'SourceEUI(KWm2)', 'SourceEUIWN(KWm2)' ])
df_stack[['OSEBuildingID', 'DataYear', 'BuildingType', 'PrimaryPropertyType', 
          'ZipCode', 'Neighborhood', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'YearBuilt', 
          'SourceEUI(KWm2)', 'SourceEUIWN(KWm2)']].groupby('OSEBuildingID').max()
```

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho did you ever sort out this issue? If so, would you comment here for those of us who haven't quite figured it out?

Comment: @LindsayVeazey Yes I sort it out, This was a regression in 1.0.0 that was fixed with '1.0.1'. Thank you for remind me to delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this error with pandas version 1.3.2 and found that the issue was coming from having two columns with the same name. So for a dataframe with columns `col1, val1, val1`, calling `df.groupby('col1').agg({'val1': np.min})` threw this error because there were two columns named `val1`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, but it was due to **NaT** pandas values on datetime columns. Be sure to use `fillna` on datetime column when this happens.

My Pandas Version is 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens in Pandas 1.1.2 also. As mentioned by Raphael Pavan the issue appears to be using `max()` or `min()` on columns that have a `np.nan` OR `None` value in them.

Use `.fillna()` to replace `None` and `NaN` values with something relevant (even an empty string) then use the agg function.