# What can cause an assertion error when attempting to obtain max() instead of mean() when resampling a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have subset and resampled a df by days which works perfectly when I try to get the mean.

```py
resampled = df.resample('D').mean()
print(resampled)
```

However, when I try to obtain the max() I get an assertion error.

```py
resampled = df.resample('D').max()
print(resampled)
```

Any ideas of where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608674/pandas-group-by-with-max-return-assertionerror. There was a problem with aggegating with `max` in 1.0.0. Upgrade if you can and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think so, I just checked I have 1.0.3 version of pandas installed.

Comment: Can you post or data, or somehow turn this into a reproducible example for others to tinker with?

Comment: Hi Ben, I just answered my own question with an update. Ok, so I just played around with it a bit and it seems to work if I specify the columns in the Dataframe.

resampled = df[["column1", "column2"]].resample('D').max()

So I guess it works this way if a bit annoying when there are lots of columns.

As someone suggested it may be related to the version of pandas. I have 1.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just played around with it a bit and it seems to work if I specify the columns in the Dataframe.

resampled = df[["column1", "column2"]].resample('D').max()

So I guess it works this way if a bit annoying when there are lots of columns.

As someone suggested it may be related to the version of pandas. I have 1.0.3.